# How to sort an object based on nested value

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object similar to the below and need to sort the top-level keys based on a deeply nested value.

```js
{
 3782034: {
    title: "",
    other_data: "",
    last_modified: {
      author: "",
      timestamp: 1584915554
    }
 },
 3981728: {
    title: "",
    other_data: "",
    last_modified: {
      author: "",
      timestamp: 1584915731
    }
 }
}
```

My goal is to have the object's top-level keys ordered by timestamp. This can either result in an object correctly ordered, or an array of ordered first-level keys (such as `[3981728, 3782034]`).

Here an example I have been working with but unable to get it working.

```
Object.entries(data).sort((a, b) => {
  return a[1].last_modified.timestamp > b[1].last_modified.timestamp
})
```

My struggle is that whenever I map the sorted keys back to an object, the sorted order doesn't persist.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: convert object keys into Array then use .sort() 
something like that Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => a - b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I was able to achieve this using the lodash `orderBy` function.

```js
const sortedKeys = orderBy(Object.keys(data), key => data[key].last_modified.timestamp, "desc")
```

I can then use this array of keys to view my object data like so:

```js
//some React component
return (
  <article>
    <p>View Data</p>
    {sortedKeys.map(key => {
      return <p>Last Modified: {data[key].title}</p>
    })}
  </article>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below, assuming your json is a variable defined as data :

```
let data_keys = Object.keys(data);
let output = data_keys.map(function (key) {
    return [key, data[key]['last_modified']['timestamp']];
}).sort(function (x, y) {
    return y[1] - x[1];
}).map(function (obj) {
    return obj.splice(0, 1)[0]
});
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects in JavaScript are unordered, so you'll have to use an ordered data structure such as an array to achieve what you're looking for.

One way to go about this is to pass the top level key and the timestamp to be sorted down the chain. After sorting based on the timestamp, then you can rebuild the object and you're left with an ordered array of objects.

```js
const values = {
  3782034: {
    title: "",
    other_data: "",
    last_modified: {
      author: "",
      timestamp: 1584915554,
    },
  },
  3981728: {
    title: "",
    other_data: "",
    last_modified: {
      author: "",
      timestamp: 1584915731,
    },
  },
};

let sorted = Object.keys(values)
  .map((key) => [key, values[key].last_modified.timestamp])
  .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
  .reduce((p, c) => [...p, {
    [c[0]]: values[c[0]]
  }], []);

console.log(sorted);
```